# Iteration that concatenates different strings based on conditions given

Tags: python, iteration

Currently having difficulty figuring out this one. I know that I am very near but I cannot figure out where I am going wrong.
I would like the output to show a string, where an even number corresponds to '?--' and an odd number corresponds to '?-', and concatenate all of the strings together. Eg. star_wars_iteration(3) should return '?-?--?-'
However, mine does not add up, it only returns it once.

```
def star_wars_iteration(num_enemy_ships): 
    counter = 1 
    result = '' 
    while counter in range(1,num_enemy_ships + 1): 
        if counter % 2 == 0: 
            return '?--' 
        elif counter % 2 == 1: 
            return '?-' 
    result = result + counter 
    counter = counter + 1
```

Comment: `return` immediately stops the execution of a function. Consider creating a second function that does the `if counter % 2` logic.

Answer (score 2):

`return` stops the function as soon as it is reached. Also you confuse `while` and `for`. What you want is:

```
def star_wars_iteration(num_enemy_ships):
    result = '' 
    for counter in range(1,num_enemy_ships + 1): 
        if counter % 2 == 0: 
            result += '?--'
        elif counter % 2 == 1:
            result += '?-'
    return result
```

Or if you want to use `while` then use `while counter <= num_enemy_ships :` (using `in range(...)` works too but is unnecessarily inefficient) and make sure the `counter = counter + 1` line is **inside** the `while` block.

Note: more concise and pythonic:

```
def star_wars_iteration(num_enemy_ships):
    return ''.join('?-' if counter % 2 else '?--' for counter in range(1,num_enemy_ships + 1))
```

Comment: Yes, exactly what I was looking for. I'll have to read up on for and while loops a bit more. However, could you pls explain why you took out the counter at the start? (counter = 1) If you did that, wouldn't there be no counter to iterate over and the code wouldn't run?

Comment: The `for` loop itself defines `counter`. You still need to define it before if you use it in a `while` loop though.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the Pythonic iterators and range function for what they are meant to be you don’t need to increment starting and end values in the range:

```
def star_wars_iteration(num_enemy_ships):
    return "".join('?-' if index % 2 else '?--' for index in range(num_enemy_ships))
```